# Question regarding multiprocessing performance in conjunction with OpenCV and PIL Image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, multiprocessing, python-imaging-library

I´m currently working on a project where I have to perform some heavy analysis on video data. Basically I have ~20 video, each 1-2h long, and function that performs my analysis. Performing analysis on one video yields a processing performance of roughly 30 FPS, so I was hoping to achieve 30 FPS when evaluating multiple videos at the same time in multiprocessing approach, this does not hold however, I rather get ~5 FPS on each video. I have 20+ CPU Cores available so the computer should in theory have enough power.
My code basically structures as follow:

```
class Task:
    def __init__(videos):
        self.videos = videos

    def execute(self):
        jobs = []
        for video in self.videos:
            worker = VideoWorker(video=video)
            jobs.append(worker)
            worker.start()

        for j in jobs:
            j.join()

class VideoWorker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, video):
        self.video = video

    def run(self):
        self.eval_video()

    def eval_video(self)
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video.path_to_video)

        while cap.isOpened():
            frame = cap.read()

            """
            ... processing
            """
            im = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            resized_im = im.resize((8, 8))

            """
            ... further processing
            """
```

The Task class manages the multiprocessing and the VideoWorker does the evaluation. I noticed while profiling the code that the Image resizing (using PIL) takes up the most CPU time, however there is big difference in computation time when employing multiprocessing or not. Without multiprocessing the resizing is done 5x-10x faster compared to the time one process needs in a multiprocessing approach.

Is there any way to speed this up or this "normal"? My assumption was that each process will run on one of the cores and thus performance would not be degraded much compared to using just one CPU. The processes do not communicate with each other and I have not yet implemented some form of result collection.

Comment: Not sure why you are using PIL and OpenCV? If you have built and installed OpenCV, you might as well use that for all your processing as it is generally much more heavily optimised than PIL, IMHO.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The resize is actually used in one of the libraries I use, not in my own implementation actually. I could sure modify the library and replace PIL with cv2.resize.

Comment: Your code is very sketchy/vague to be able to comment much. If that's all you can show, I think you're going to have to do some careful benchmarking to work out what's going on.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yea I agree its vague, but from profiling results the other steps did seem to have a reasonable impact. I'll see if I can switch from PIL resize to cv2.resize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching from PIL.Image.resize to OpenCV's cv2.resize did the trick as already suggested in the comments.